# How to programatically save a notebook created by CreateDocument

Tags: notebooks

I've already written code that generates about 20 notebooks using "CreateDocument" and I was wondering if there exists a method to automatically save them. Is there an easy way to create a notebook and save it programatically, i.e. without manually saving the notebook?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NotebookSave` is your friend, it's usage is quite straightforward:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{"hello"}];
NotebookSave[nb, FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "tst.nb"}]]
```

If you didn't save the `NotebookObject` that `CreateDocument` returns to a variable you can use `Notebooks[]` to get that, the following is an example that selects by `WindowTitle`:

```
nb = Select[Notebooks[], 
        AbsoluteCurrentValue[#, WindowTitle] === "Untitled-1" &][[1]]
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds. +1

Comment: @rcollyer: I bet your answer would have been somewhat more elaborate, though :-)

Comment: Not in this case. I probably would have linked to the docs, and given a very bare bones answer.